# How do you assign a pointer to an existing variable in a std::vector?

Tags: pointers, reference, stdvector

I'm trying to create a tree-like hierarchy of nodes.
Each Node is stored in a std::vector and has an int value and a Node* parent, pointing to another Node in the vector, in this case the most recently added element. It looks like the parent values are uninitialised but not sure how this is the case. Any help would be appreciated.

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int v = -1, Node* p = nullptr) : value(v), parent(p) {}
    int value;
    Node* parent;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> m_vector;
    m_vector.push_back(Node(1));

    Node n1 = m_vector.back();
    m_vector.push_back(Node(2, &m_vector[0]));
}

// m_vector[1].parent->value = -572662307.
```

Comment: Perhaps you could store some other thing like a primary key or an index, rather than a pointer.  Or use a `std::list` instead of a vector. Or use a tree container like `std::map` or perhaps third party trees

Comment: Will use indices, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **!!! DON'T !!!**

It is entirely possible that when you call push_back, if the array needs to be resized, every pointer will now be invalid. If you erase an element from the start of the array, every pointer value you store there will be invalid.

In this particular instance, you'd be better off using an integer index. That will still cause issues when you remove elements from the vector (i.e. decrement each index that is greater than the index you are erasing), but at least you wont have issues when you are adding the elements.

Comment: That was my backup option, don't think i'll need to remove elements but i'll write methods for handling it if i need to, thanks for the response